# Could not resolve... image importation in REACT deploy

Tags: reactjs, image, deployment, vite, netlify

i have this problem when i try to deploy my SPA[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuFHN.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVm3a.jpg)

the URL is fine because in localhost y can see it. but the problem is with the deploy in netlify.

is there any solution?

I am trying to deploy my application on netlify